# Loop through only one type of usercontrol in stackPanel WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, loops

I have two `UserControl` with just one/two textblocks.On my window, i add the first `UserControl` couple o' times in a for each loop and the 2nd user control,i just add it in the end,which mean i have only 1 `UserControl2`.

```
public class test
{
 UserControl1 btn = new UserControl1;

 private void thread1()
 {
foreach (var item in mycollection)///i am not including the actual iteration target because it is a class and then the post might be too huge
{

    mystack.Children.Add(btn);
}

mystack.Children.Add(new UserControl2);

}
```

Note that i am adding only the `UserControl1` in the `foreach` loop but i am adding `UserControl2` outside the loop,which means i am adding it for once.

Anyway,i may iterate through all the controls i added to `mystack` in a `foreach` loop like :

```
foreach (var control in mystack.Children)
{
////My codes here
}
```

As i mentioned earlier,there are 2 types of `UserControl`s added to the `StackPanel`.How do i only iterate through one type of `UserControl` only ? I mean what if i want to iterate through only the `UserControl1` s from the `Stackpanel`(mystack) ?

I tried something like :

```
private void thread2()
{

foreach (UserControl1 control in mystack.Children)
{
}
 //////Or

for (i = o; i <= mystack.children - 1; i++)
{
 btn.height = 10 /// my other codes here :)
}}
```

But both of them throw `Unable to cast object of type UserControl2 to UserControl1` exception which means it is iterating through all the controls(both `UserControl1` and `UserControl2`) :(

See the first code black in the post?Some might suggest doing whatever i wanna do in the first `foreach` loop but i cant,this has to be done in different threads(first loop in `thread1` and the rest in `thread2`...So,how should i achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method OfType to filter children by their type

```
        foreach (UserControl1 control in mystack.Children.OfType<UserControl1>())
        {

        }
```

Comment: but in my loop `foreach (UserControl1 control in mystack.Children)` doesn't it get the type automatically ?

Comment: Yes it does. OfType<UserControl1> filter out all controls that are on of type UserControl1

Comment: @user9530640 Sorry, I somehow misunderstood your question. If you execute ```foreach (UserControl1 control in mystack.Children)``` and some of children are not of type UserControl1, then there will be some exception, probably cast exception or similar

Answer (score -2):

What if do some reflection:

```
Type t = typeof(yourControl);
if (t == typeof(int)) // or whatever you need
    // Some code here
```

typeof takes a type name (which you specify at compile time).
Or you can use GetType too:

```
if(yourcontrol.GetType() == typeof(yourControl))
//code here
```

GetType gets the runtime type of an instance.

Comment: before i try it , take a look at my post again , as per ur logic , should `foreach (UserControl1 control in mystack.Children)` do the same ? even this should get the `UserControl1`s only , right ? anyways, i'll give ur solution a try

Comment: wait....i don't see any loop in your answer ??? I need to loop through the controls , i mentioned that in the post clearly

Comment: typeof(instanceOfObjectHere) won't compile

Comment: this is very wrong :( .... Please don't give misleading answers :)

Comment: I forgot to give a straitgh answer...i should use a foreach and put all your options there. 
I just said...use reflection same as Eugene did